# Should this program work to guess a 7-character password?

Tags: java, passwords

I created this program which is supposed to guess a 7-character password. When I run it, nothing really happens. Is this program correct? If there's something wrong, please tell me what to change. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inputReal = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter real password (7 characters):");
    String realpassword = inputReal.nextLine();
    String finalpassword = "";
    char real1 = realpassword.charAt(0);
    char real2 = realpassword.charAt(1);
    char real3 = realpassword.charAt(2);
    char real4 = realpassword.charAt(3);
    char real5 = realpassword.charAt(4);
    char real6 = realpassword.charAt(5);
    char real7 = realpassword.charAt(6);

    CharSequence avaliableChars = "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm!@#$%^&*()?";





    char guess1;
    char guess2;
    char guess3;
    char guess4;
    char guess5;
    char guess6;
    char guess7;
    boolean notFound = true;
   while(notFound) { 

   for(int i1 = 0; i1<47 && notFound == true; i1++) {
       guess1 = avaliableChars.charAt(i1);
       for(int i2 = 0; i2<47 && notFound == true; i2++) {
           guess2 = avaliableChars.charAt(i2);
           for(int i3 = 0; i3<47 && notFound == true; i3++) {
               guess3 = avaliableChars.charAt(i3);
               for(int i4 = 0; i4<47 && notFound == true; i4++) {
                   guess4 = avaliableChars.charAt(i4);
                   for(int i5 = 0; i5<47 && notFound == true; i5++) {
                       guess5 = avaliableChars.charAt(i5);
                       for(int i6 = 0; i6<47 && notFound == true; i6++) {
                           guess6 = avaliableChars.charAt(i6);
                           for(int i7 = 0; i7<47 && notFound == true; i7++) {
                               guess7 = avaliableChars.charAt(i7);
                               String guessedpassword = "" + guess1 + guess2 + guess3 + guess4 + guess5 + guess6 + guess7;
                               if(guessedpassword.equals(realpassword)) {
                                  finalpassword = guessedpassword;
                                  notFound = false;
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
System.out.println("Guessed password:" + finalpassword);    
}
```

I ran it, and just waited for about 3-5 minutes. Nothing happened after I put in the real password.

Comment: In the worst case, you are doing 47^7 iterations of the innermost loop. That is over 500 billion iterations. That is going to take a long time to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the program works, I just tested it with an easy password "1111115".

The problem is just the timing of the brute force is insane. The time complexity is O(n^7), and given any password that doesnt start with a number, like "a111111", the computer is doing a minimum of 1.07x10^10 operations, thats over 10 billion operations, which will take quite a long time.

For reassurance though, your algorithm works.

Bonus: Experiment with how fast your computer can do things. This 50 billion loop program actually runs in about 14 seconds on my computer, so tinker with it and see how you can make your original program faster!

```
public class fast {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long x = 1000000000;
    String s = "abc";
    boolean bool = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < 50; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
            char a = s.charAt(2);
            // try different things, like using arrays instead of strings, etc.
        }
    }

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("took " + (endTime-startTime) + " ms);
}
}
```

Comment: So how long would it actually take to do?